# How to disable Opera mouse shortcuts?

Tags: windows-xp, opera

I dont want to go to previous/next page when I click left+right mouse button or right+left mouse button.

I tried to delete all possible key settings I found, but I just failed. How can I disable this feature?

I have newest Opera version installed.

**Edit:** I have tried `Settings > Preferences > Advanced > Shortcuts` and disabled mouse gestures, but it doesn't work. Maybe the bug is because I installed new opera version over the old folder?

Comment: If you think so (Install newer version over older) then just uninstall it through Revo uninstaller then install it again and then try to disable them again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to uncheck `opera:config#UserPrefs|EnableMouseFlips` - enter as the URL in the address bar.

> Enable forward and backward navigation via mouse flips.

Comment: where can i find that?

Comment: @Rookie it's path to **opera:config** so just paste this to the address field. Don't forget to save changes.

Comment: that worked! how the hell that wasnt in the "real" settings page?! is there any other way going to that settings page than some mystic "opera:config" url?

Comment: Anyone have any idea how to do this in the latest version of Opera? (29.0)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this step :

To enable or disable mouse gestures, select

```
Settings > Preferences > Advanced > Shortcuts,
```

and check or uncheck “Enable mouse gestures”.

Comment: Yes, i have tried... i pressed it off but it doesnt work. could it be a bug when i installed new opera over the old folder?

Comment: deleted all the entries which begin with gesture etc in "Preferences > Advanced > Shortcuts > Mouse movements > Application" if you cannot done with enable or disable menu

Comment: i did delete all entries... i deleted all possible keyshortcuts too... nothing seems to work.

Comment: it seems you need clean all your old opera's dump file. and try to installing the latest one.